# how to change meta title and meta description in after filter of category page

Tags: category, frontend

I want to change category page after filter opens any page and change Title, MetaTitle, MetaDescription in after search result.

What can I do ..and any observer this possible ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this observer code in `controller_action_postdispatch`

```
<?php

namespace ABC\Seo\Observer;

class FileName implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $context;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,

    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }  
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        //your code 
        $layout = $this->context->getLayout();
        $pageMainTitle = $layout->getBlock('page.main.title');
        $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($categoryname); 

    }
```